# When is an element of an extension field in the base field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

Given a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$, consider an extension of it; $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$. If I'm given $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{p^m}$, then, if $\alpha^p = \alpha$, $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{p}$.

Why is this true?

Answer (score 3):

The equation $x^p-x=0$ has at most $p$ roots. But it has $p$ roots within $\Bbb F_p$. So any root in an extension of $\Bbb F_p$ already lies in $\Bbb F_p$.